# Create moving Buttons in WinForms like Wpf

Tags: c#

I need when my Main form will open three buttons to be moved one by one somewhere in my form and creating My Menu Bar. I want doing this only for styling my form.

I found this code but I don't know how to stop it in a certain position and which will be the speed moving.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Left++;

    int buttonMoveLimit = label1.Left - button1.Width;

    if (button1.Left >= buttonMoveLimit)
    {
        button1.Left = buttonMoveLimit;
        SetTimer(false);
    }
}
private void SetTimer(bool enabled)
{
    timer1.Enabled = enabled;
    button1.Text = timer1.Enabled ? "Moving!" : "Moved!";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetTimer(!timer1.Enabled);
}
```

I want make something like this in WinForm
[This is created with VS Blend](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmweCM_8khZmiCdkH-HYkmiHZOm4)

Comment: Are you attempting to set the initial style, like in the designer? or are you changing the position based on size of the form?

Comment: As this is like the third guy working on the same homework assignment.. I'd say he wants the button to move across the screen to a certain position.  HINT: control speed with timer interval.